# How to make a search shortcut for Super User in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, search, google-chrome-extensions

Many times I find myself searching superuser.com through google (I find it much better than internal superuser.com search).

Therefore I write in Chrome address bar: "some term I want to find site:superuser.com". I'd like to have some sort of shortcut for that and instead of site:superuser.com write @super or something similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add search shortcut to your [omnibox](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95440) in Google chrome.
Right click on the **omnibox** and click **Edit search engines...**. You will get a dialogue box for editing search engines.

[image]

In other search engines section add Google search for superuser.com

1. Give a name for your new search engine (**Google Supeuser.com**)
2. Give a keyword for this (**su**)
3. Give the url as **http://www.google.com/search?q=site:superuser.com+%s**

[image]

Here %s will be replaced by your search term. You can add any [Google search operators](http://www.google.com/intl/en/help/operators.html) to this.

Now you can use the keyword (**su**) for searching superuser.com.
Just type **su** in the **omnibox** and press **tab** key, and enter your search terms.
Note that on pressing the tab key Chrome will display the name given for the search engine (Google Supeuser.com).

[image]

This will show results from superuser.com alone.

Answer (score 3):

Just reverse what you're currently doing more or less.

Start typing supe... superuser.com will appear in the omnibar. Press tab or space and you can now search in superuser.com from the omnibar.

[image: It should look like this]

Comment: Searching for `superuser.com foo` is different from searching for `site:superuser.com foo`. Page 1 results include [this](http://superuser.blogoverflow.com) and [this](http://foontic.net/www.superuser.com) for the former search (I am located in Germany, for reference).

Comment: @Daniel Beck: I can confirm the results are different. I find the method I describe above to be more useful as it lands one in SU, not in a Google results page. Nonetheless the poster is *specifically* asking to search `site:superuser.com` so my answer is incorrect. I'm getting quite different results to the ones you linked for what it's worth. @Jack Juiceson - I'd go with what @WarFox describes.